# C Get function line number from within 2 function calls

Tags: c, gcc

In the process of developing a small SDK, I need to create an "error handler". To make more effective I want to get the line number where the function was called and I don't know if it's possible in C (using GCC for compiling).

When a SDK function is called, the SDK function itself will call the error handler function if an error occurred.

With that I'd like to know if there is a way to know the line number from the user source code that called the function.

Example :

User.c :

```
main{ CallSDKFunction(); }
```

SDK.a file :

```
void CallSDKFunction( void ){ if ( ERROR ){ CallERRORHandler(); } }
```

...
...
...

```
void CallERRORHandler( void ){ // Here I want to know in which line in user.c the CallSDKFunction was called}
```

Comment: Yes I know :) I have found how to modify original question and removed the bad ones and added the missing ones ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One approach is to pass the `__FILE__` and `__LINE__` to the SDK function, and then have the SDK function pass them on to the error handler function. However, the user won't want to be bothered with that, so you need to define a macro in the SDK's header file that hides the details. The macro would look like this

```
#define CallSDKFunction(a,b) actualSDKFunction( __FILE__, __LINE__, a, b )
```

The user would call the SDK with code like this.  Note that the user doesn't need to know that the `__FILE__` and `__LINE__` are being passed to the SDK function. The macro takes care of that.

```
int main( void )
{
    int a = 3;
    int b = 4;
    int result = CallSDKFunction( a, b );  
    printf( "%d\n", result );
}
```

And the SDK implementation would be something like this

```
int actualSDKFunction( const char *fileStr, int lineNum, int a, int b )
{
    if ( a+b > 5 )
        CallERRORHandler( fileStr, lineNum );
    return( a+b );
}

void CallERRORHandler( const char *fileStr, int lineNum )
{
    printf( "Bad values in file %s at line %d\n", fileStr, lineNum );
}
```

Comment: Wow ! Thank you a lot.
From what I understood (I'm french so my english is not perfect :p ), it's exactly what I need.

Answer (score 1):

If I have understood your requirement properly, you can make use of `__FILE__`and `__LINE__` MACRO to get the filename and the line number of any instruction. These two are standard predefined MACRO. You can check [Online GCC reference](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Standard-Predefined-Macros.html).

Also, there is [`__func__`](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Function-Names.html) (`C99`) which gives you the *current* function name.

So, as you want, you can define the another function prototype (maybe in `debug` mode), which passes on (and accepts) the extra parameters like `__FILE__`, `__LINE__`, `__func__` etc while making the function call. Then , you can have the caller function name and line displayed from the called function.

Alternatively, you can also have a look at [`backtrace()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/backtrace.3.html) function. However, it is a GNU extension.

Answer (score 1):

The C preprocessor has the special tokens `__LINE__` and `__FILE__`, which expand to the current line (as integer) and the current file (as C string).

To make it work, you must declare a wrapper macro:

```
void error(int line, const char *file)
{
    fprintf(stderr, "Error in %s, line %d\n", file, line);
    // handle error
}

#define ERROR() error(__LINE__, __FILE__)
```

This will pass the information on the location of the macro invocation to the error handler.